# StandardScaler.inverse_transform() return the same array as input :/ Is sklearn broken or am I?

Tags: python, syntax, statistics, sklearn-pandas

Good evening,

I'm currently pursuing a PhD in chemistry and in this framework I'm trying to apply my few knowledge in python and stats to discriminate sample based on their IR spectrum.
After a few of weeks of data acquisition I'm finally able to build my data set and was about to see what PCA can offer (this was the easy part).

I was able to build my script and get the loadings, scores and everything else that I could possibly need or want. However I used the StandardScaler from sklearn.preprocessing to scale down my data so (correct my if i'm wrong) I should get back loadings in this "standard scaled" space.

As my data are actual IR spectra those loadings have a chemical meanings (even thought there are not real spectrum) e.g. if my PC1 loadings have a peak at XX cm-1 i know that samples with high PC1 are likely to contain compounds that absorb at this wavenumber .
So i want to reverse the StandardScaler transformation. I've tried to used StandardScaler.inverse_transform() however it appears to return me the same array that I gave him... which is very frustrating...
I'm trying to do the same thing with my samples spectrum but it gave me the same result again : here is the portion of my script where I tried this :

```
Wavenumbers = DFF.columns   
#in fact this is a little more complicated but that's the spirit
Spectre = DFF.values.tolist() 
#btw DFF is my pandas.dataframe containing spectrum with features = wavenumber 

SS = StandardScaler(copy=True)
DFF  = SS.fit_transform(DFF)      #at this point I use SS for preprocessing before PCA

#I'm then trying to inverse SS and get back the 1rst spectrum of the dataset

D = SS.inverse_transform(DFF[0])

#However at this point DFF[0] and D are almost-exactly the same I'm sure because :
plt.plot(Wavenumbers,D)
plt.plot(Wavenumbers,DFF[0]) #the curves are the sames, and :

for i,j in enumerate(D) : 
  if j==DFF[0][i] : pass
  else : print("{}".format(j-DFF[0][i] )) #return nothing bigger than 10e-16
```

The problem is more than likely syntax or how i used StandardScaler, however i have no one around me to search for help with that . Can anyone tell me what i did wrong ? or give me an hint on how i could get back my loadings in the "actual real IR spectra" space ?

PS: sorry for the wacky English and i hope to be understandable

Comment: I dunno if it's worth the trouble to sort out what's going on with StandardScaler or whatever. PCA is conceptually straightforward so why not just do it by hand. Harassing StandardScaler into doing what you want can't be any easier than just doing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks but you know IR spectra are actualy quite large and doing by-hand PCA as you suggest seems to be a huge waste of time. I'm about to build my own StandardScaler (which is not that difficult) but before that i wanted to be sure that i didn't made a stupid mistake. 
Furthermore i'm not a tech guy so if i can i prefer to use built in library instead of a homemade function.

Comment: and btw StandardScaler is designed to do exactly what i want to do. Hence my desperation when i can't manage to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Good evening,

After putting the problem aside for a few days I finally re-coded the function I needed (as suggested by Robert Dodier).

For reminder, I wanted to have a function that could take my data from a pandas dataframe  and mean-centered it in order to do PCA, but also that could reverse the preprocessing for latter uses.

Here is the code I ended up with :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Scaler:
  std =[]
  mean = []
  def fit(self,DF):
    self.std=[]
    self.mean=[]
    for c in DF.columns:
      self.std.append(DF[c].std())
      self.mean.append(DF[c].mean())
  def transform(self,DF):
    X = np.zeros(shape=DF.shape)
    for i,c in enumerate(DF.columns):
      for j in range(len(DF.index)):
        X[j][i] = (DF[c][j] - self.mean[i]) / self.std[i] 
    return X
  def reverse(self,X):
    Y = np.zeros(shape=X.shape)
    for i in range(len(X[0])):
      for j in range(len(X)):
        Y[j][i] = X[j][i] * self.std[i] + self.mean[i]
    return Y
  def fit_transform(self,DF):
    self.fit(DF)
    X = self.transform(DF)
    return X
```

It's pretty slow and surely very low-tech but it seems to do the job just fine. Hope it will save some time to other python beginners.
I designed it to be as close as I think sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler does it.

example :

```
S = Scaler() #create scaler object
S.fit(DF) #fit the scaler to the dataframe (calculate mean and std for every columns in DF /!\ DF must be a pd.dataframe)
X=S.transform(DF) # return a np.array with mean centered data
Y = S.reverse(X) # reverse the transformation to get back original data
```

Again sorry for the fast tipped English. And thanks to Robert for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my evaluation, using **StandardScaler()**, the results matched up to 2 decimal points. You might consider experimenting with higher precision. As the outputs are NumPy arrays, you can round them to a specific precision using the .round(2) method and then make comparisons.

The precision of calculations in scikit-learn (sklearn) depends on the specific implementation. I suggest printing the outputs to better understand the precision.